# Updating matplotlib plot inside a callback

Tags: python, matplotlib, callback, ros

I have a plot of an occupancy grid map that I'm trying to update, whenever a callback is triggered. The following code shows the callback, that takes laser scan data as input (using `rospy`), updates an occupancy grid map using this data, and then plots the grid map for the user:

```
def lidar_callback(self, scan: LaserScan):
    scan_parameters = [scan.angle_min, scan.angle_max, scan.angle_increment]
    scan_ranges = np.array(scan.ranges)

    self.mapper.update_map(self.pose, scan_ranges, scan.angle_min, scan.angle_increment)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.matshow(self.mapper.probability_map(), cmap="Greys")
    plt.draw()
```

For a single iteration, the occupancy grid map output is a follows:

[image: Occupancy grid map for single lidar scan]

However, the code above creates a new plot *whenever* the callback is triggered, instead of keeping a single plot and updating it when new lidar data is processed. Since the `lidar_callback()` function is part of a larger `MapperNode` class, I tried to solve this problem by moving the `fig` variable to the `__init__()` constructor of the `MapperNode` class, giving the following code,

```
class MapperNode:
    def __init__(self, pose: Pose, mapper: Mapper):
        self.pose = pose
        self.mapper = mapper

        rospy.Subscriber("scan", LaserScan, self.lidar_callback)
        rospy.Subscriber("odom", Odometry, self.odometry_callback)

        self.fig = plt.figure()

    def lidar_callback(self, scan: LaserScan):
        scan_parameters = [scan.angle_min, scan.angle_max, scan.angle_increment]
        scan_ranges = np.array(scan.ranges)

        self.mapper.update_map(self.pose, scan_ranges, scan.angle_min, scan.angle_increment)
       
        ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.matshow(self.mapper.probability_map(), cmap="Greys")
        plt.draw()
```

But now, when using `self.fig` when trying to define `ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)`, I get the following error:

```
ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
AttributeError: 'MapperNode' object has no attribute 'fig'
```

So it seems that I'm unable to define a `plt.figure()` object in the constructor and use it later on in another function in the class. Does anyone know what mistake I'm making in trying to update an existing figure inside a callback? If there's a better way to show/update the occupancy grid map I'd be more than happy to know about it. Thanks!

Comment: you have to use python 2.x because ROS does not support 3.x in some cases

Answer (score 0):

you may try this,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rospy
import tf
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from tf.transformations import quaternion_matrix
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

class Visualiser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')
        self.max_x = 300
        self.max_y = 300
    
    def plot_init(self):
        self.ax.set_xlim(0, self.max_x)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, self.max_y)
        return self.ln  

    def update_plot(self, frame):
        # data_map = np.random.randint(60, size=(60, 60))
        # self.ax.matshow(data_map, cmap="Greys")
        self.ax.matshow(self.mapper.probability_map(), cmap="Greys")
        return self.ln
    
    def lidar_callback(self, scan):
        scan_parameters = [scan.angle_min, scan.angle_max, scan.angle_increment]
        scan_ranges = np.array(scan.ranges)
        self.mapper.update_map(self.pose, scan_ranges, scan.angle_min, scan.angle_increment)


rospy.init_node('lidar_visual_node')
vis = Visualiser()
sub = rospy.Subscriber('/scan', LaserScan, vis.lidar_callback)
ani = FuncAnimation(vis.fig, vis.update_plot, init_func=vis.plot_init)
plt.show(block=True)
```

Note: set the proper values for `self.max_x` and `self.max_y`, I tested with a random map. Let me know if this work for you

For example, [image]